# How do I make a Chart Helper X-Axis start at a value other than zero?

Tags: asp.net

I am using the Chart Helper in an ASP.Net (Razor v3) website that gets its data from a SQL Server stored procedure. The X-Axis values returned from the query are:

6,7,8...26,1,2,3,4,5

When the chart is displayed it has the X-Axis start at 1 and go to 26. How do I make it match the data?

The code for the chart is:

```
@{ 
var db = Database.Open("BITool");
var data = db.Query("Exec SalesOps.AccountOrders @Account=@0", App.AccountListID);
```

}

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 835, height: 200, themePath: "chartThemeYellow.xml")
    .AddTitle("Account Medical Orders")
    .AddSeries("Default",
        xValue: data, xField: "Segment",
        yValues: data, yFields: "Orders")
    .Write();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by converting the xValue data to char(2) in the SQL query. Now the ChartHelper displays the values in the order they are in the query instead of starting from zero as it does when they are numeric values.

This can be closed.